# Замена текста во всех txt-файлах в одной папке

Tags: c#

Я знаю как заменить текст в одном `txt`-файле, но что делать, если мне нужно изменить все `txt`-файлы в целевой папке?

Мой код (редактирование одного `txt`-файла):

```
string text = File.ReadAllText("Путь к моей папке с txt-файлами", "*.txt");
text = text.Replace("some text", "new value");
File.WriteAllText("test.txt", text);
```

Comment: У вас ошибка, у метода `File.ReadAllText` нет перегрузки, которая принимает два аргумента типа `String`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно использовать метод [`Directory.GetFiles(String, String)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles("Путь к моей папке с тхт файлами", "*.txt");
foreach (var file in files)
{
    string text = File.ReadAllText(file);
    text = text.Replace("some text", "new value");
    File.WriteAllText(file, text);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать несколько блоков try-catch, чтобы не вылететь с ошибкой, а файлы получить с помощью [Directory.GetFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.directory.getfiles(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
try
{
    var txtFiles = Directory
       .GetFiles("C:\\path", "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
       .ToList();

    txtFiles.ForEach(file =>
    {
        try
        {
            var oldText = File.ReadAllText(file);
            File.WriteAllText(file, oldText.Replace("match", "new value"));
            Console.WriteLine(@"Текст в файле '{0}' успешно изменен.", file);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(@"Ошибка чтения/записи файла '{0}' {1}",
            file, exception.Message);
        }
    });
}     
catch (Exception exception)      
{
    Console.WriteLine(@"Ошибка получения списка файлов. Error: {0}",
    exception.Message);
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43899/discussion-on-answer-by-denis-bubnov-----txt----).